# Is there a fast way to query distinct column values in a huge hdf5 table with pytables?

Tags: hdf5, pytables

I've got a giant-sized hdf5 file consisting of one table, 26 columns, about 3 billion rows (no way it's going to fit in memory). I did a lot of Googling and couldn't find a fast way to query distinct values for a column or group of columns. Is there a way that's faster than iterating through all rows and building lists?

Comment: dts, this is where pytables shines with 'in-kernel searches'. First, they say the have excellent performance up to 10 billion rows. :-) And, the various `.where()` methods do exactly what you want. `.where()` returns a row iterator, but you can also return a list of coordinates (rows) with `.get_where_list()` or a np array with `.read_where()`. It clearly explained in their docs: [Pytables table.where](https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/libref/structured_storage.html#tables.Table.where)

Comment: Yes I read and re-read that documentation and I'm doing some "where" queries on this dataset, but I don't see how to slap together something equivalent to an SQL SELECT DISTINCT query ... Googling this problem seemed to just show a bunch of weird stuff that wasn't directly applicable from people who have my problem. Any further hints?

Comment: I don't know SQL, so don't know what a SELECT DISTINCT query is. Look at the condition parameter. It references the field/column names. Without knowing specifics of your data, it's hard to give more details. 'Field_name == value" would return all rows that match that value. You can use booleans  to build more sophisticated queries.

Comment: No need to know about the data, it's a very general task ... my table has, say, 3 billion rows. Column "Col1" takes only 1000 different values over the 3 billion rows. I need to get a list of those 1000 distinct values. This is easy, fast and basic for any relational database, but my understanding (perhaps flawed) is that it's a hassle for hdf5.

Comment: You can combine pytables `table.col()` or `table.read()` with numpy `array.unique()` to get what you need. Short example in answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows how to extract a column of data from Pytables Table to a Numpy array, then use the Numpy `np.unique()` method to get a new array of unique values only. Option to get an array of unique values and counts of each value also shown.

```
mytable = h5_file.root.YOUR_DATASET

Col1_array = mytable.col('Col1')
# above statement is equivalent to:
Col1_array = mytable.read(field='Col1')

# get array of unique values:
uarray = np.unique(Col1_array)

# if you also want an array of counts for each unique value:
uarray, carray = np.unique(Col1_array, return_counts=True)
```

Comment: That works to get the result, but it appears to be not really any faster than iterating over the entire table and using defaultdict to build the unique list. This observation is from testing both methods using a mini-sized table of 220 million records. I figured pytables would have something fancy and not-well-documented for this.

Build dict time =  318.5 seconds, size = 4522
Get sym_array time =  212.0 seconds
Get unique time =  87.4 seconds
Count uniques = 4522
Number of rows in table: 221264142

Comment: I don't work with relational databases, so can't add much more. There is an interesting approach discussed on SourceForge: [PyTables - Hierarchical datasets](https://sourceforge.net/p/pytables/mailman/message/22387552/) HDF5 is not a RDB, and I'm unaware of  "SQL like" capabilities in Pytables. Maybe **HDFql** can help? See info here: [HDFql](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hdfql/info) Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, those links were helpful. The HDFql I doubt speeds anything up, but it looks like I can use it to build the hdf5 COM plug-in that I need. The SourceForge link looked promising, but I tried the two "fast" methods given there and they both took roughly as long as your method and my method. I'm going to close this as answered, "no, there is no fast method."

Comment: just a general comment here... `numpy.unique` is going to sort your results!  this can be quite time-consuming... try using `pandas.unique` which by definition leaves your values unsorted and might give quite some speedup for very large arrays